# Proxy pass on Apache redirects instead of proxying

Tags: apache-httpd, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am trying to proxy an http service running on the same machine using apache proxy pass. When I try to connect to my subdomain.domain.com, I am redirected to 127.0.0.1, which is the address that I am trying to proxy with apache. It used to work on an older version of apache, then I updated the whole system and stopped working. The machine is running debian 8 and the last version of Apache2.

Here you can see my configuration for the virtual host.

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName subdomain.domain.com
ServerAlias www.subdomain.domain.com
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyVerify none
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/myssl/subdomain.domain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/myssl/subdomain.domain.key

<Proxy *>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please clarify. How is it 'not working'? Do you get an error message? If so, post it. Do you see something in the logs? If so, post it. etc.

Comment: When I try to connect to my subdomain.domain.com, I am redirected to 127.0.0.1, which is the address that I am trying to proxy with apache, instead of getting the address 127.0.0.1:8888 proxied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happened to me, the solution was the following: You must add

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
```